# Is it possible to break on the same line?

Tags: javascript, case, break

Normal way:

```
switch(whaa){

   case 1:
     if(condition){
       xxx();
       break;
     }

}
```

but can I break in the same line as my code to avoid the { } ?

Like

```
switch(whaa){

   case 1:
     if(condition)
       break xxx();

}
```

this doesn't work obviously, but perhaps there's a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the inclusion of brackets, only the first statement gets executed. 
So the second statement will execute outside of `if`.

<strike>You could however use comma operator to make it a single statement and hence remove the usage of brackets. However, you must focus on **quality over quantity**.</strike>

```
if(condition)
  xxx(), break;
```

What the above does is evaluate to `break` after executing `xxx()` in the way.

As pointed by thefourtheye, `break` is a statement and hence can't be used as an expression using comma operator.

So it has to be used as an independent statement, so the brackets cannot be removed.

Comment: `break` is a statement. You have used it like an expression.

Comment: @thefourtheye ok. Thought it would work. Thanks anyway.